# Iterate over array whilst amending the same array

Tags: ruby

The following array iteration works OK

```
data = [17, 22, 12, 24]
data.each do |item| 
   puts "number: #{item}"
end
```

I would like each new string to be inserted into the same array instead of doing `puts`. The following approach fails with no error. I'm not sure if this is creating an infinite loop.

```
data = [17, 22, 12, 24]
data.each do |item| 
    data << "number: #{item}"
 end
```

I also tried `insert` instead of `<<`, but the same issue comes along.

Comment: What the expected end result? `data = [17, 22, 12, 24, "number: 17", "number: 22", "number: 12", "number 24"]` / `["number: 17", "number: 22", "number: 12", "number 24"]`?

Comment: What do you mean by "fail"?

Comment: Look at [Array#map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Array.html#method-i-map)

Comment: Block doesn't return, memory goes up, CPU at 100%; yes, this looks like an infinite loop.

Comment: It's easy to see why this is an infinite loop: `each` iterates over *all* elements of the array and at each iteration of the loop you add a new element at the end of the array, so there will always be at least one more element to iterate over. So, you are creating an infinitely large array while you are iterating over it, and this will obviously take an infinite amount of time and require an infinite amount of space.

Comment: @JörgWMittag it depends on how `each` is implemented, specifically if the array's length is evaluated on each iteration (it is). On the other hand, `data.reverse_each { |i| data.unshift "..." }` does *not* result in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add the new items to the array, do:

```
data = [17, 22, 12, 24]
data.concat data.collect{|i| "number: #{i}"}
# data => [17, 22, 12, 24, "number: 17", "number: 22", "number: 12", "number: 24"]
```

If you just want to replace the content of data with the new items:

```
data = data.collect{|i| "number: #{i}"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Array#map!` method:

```
data = [17, 22, 12, 24]
data.map! { |item| "number: #{item}" }
```

result:

```
["number: 17", "number: 22", "number: 12", "number: 24"]
```